# A better way to check POST params?

Tags: validation, go, struct, conditional-statements

I'm currently working on setting up an API using Golang. I'm making a signup route and I need to check that everything is filled in my `SignupModel`. So for now I'm using a **very** long if condition.. I'm sure there must be more efficient/elegant solutions, but I somehow cannot find them.

Here is a code snippet:

```
// My SignupModel
type SignupModel struct {
    ID        string `json:"id"`
    Username  string `json:"username"`
    FbToken   string `json:"fbtoken"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string `json:"lastname"`
    Picture   string `json:"picture"`
}

// This is the condition I'm using inside my route (I know it's terrible)
if signup.ID != "" && signup.Username != "" && signup.FbToken == "" && signup.Email == "" && signup.Firstname == "" && signup.Lastname == "" && signup.Picture == "" {        
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(signup)
} else {
    statusResponse := StatusResponse{Status: "Something went wrong", StatusCode: 401}
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(statusResponse)
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your code looks fine. It isn't terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a general helper function which uses reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) to check all fields of a struct:

```
func check(s interface{}) error {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    for i := v.NumField() - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if v.Field(i).Interface() == "" {
            return fmt.Errorf("Field %s is empty!", v.Type().Field(i).Name)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Using it:

```
fmt.Println(check(SignupModel{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}))
fmt.Println(check(SignupModel{}))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SAdjZYUVmE)):

```
<nil>
Field Picture is empty!
```

**Improvements:**

The above `check()` function works for all types, not just for `SignupModel`, but currently –as it is– only handles fields of `string` type. You can improve it if you want to support other field types.

Here's an improved version which handles fields of other types too, and it also handles if the passed value is a pointer to a struct (simply dereferences it). If a non-`struct` value is passed, it returns an error:

```
func check(s interface{}) error {
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(s))
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return fmt.Errorf("Not struct!")
    }
    v2 := reflect.Zero(v.Type())
    for i := v.NumField() - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if v.Field(i).Interface() == v2.Field(i).Interface() {
            return fmt.Errorf("Field %s is empty!", v.Type().Field(i).Name)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(check(&struct{ I int }{1}))
fmt.Println(check(struct{ I int }{}))
fmt.Println(check(struct { I int; S string }{1, "a"}))
fmt.Println(check(&struct { I int; S string }{}))
fmt.Println(check("I'm a string"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IrLJNRp2dL)):

```
<nil>
Field I is empty!
<nil>
Field S is empty!
Not struct!
```

**Final notes:**

The above solution uses reflection which is always slower than direct code (the one you're trying to shorten). But since we're talking about HTTP `POST` requests, the performance difference is negligible (as an HTTP `POST` request could take **hundreds of milliseconds** while this `check()` function takes **half a microsecond** when called with a value of your `SignupModel` type – benchmarked).

If you'd want to mix the speed of your code and the flexibility of this, one option would be to create a generator (`go generate`, read blog post: [Generating code](https://blog.golang.org/generate)) which would generate unique `checkXX()` helper functions, one for each distinct struct type, operating without reflection (using direct field value comparisons).

Comment: Amazingly detailed answer. Thank you very much @icza !

Comment: Keep in mind that a code using reflection is much slower than one not using it, like the original approach.

Comment: @cd1 Yes, you're right. But since we're already talking about HTTP POST requests, the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @icza Mind to explain why it would be negligible in HTTP POST requests ? Also, using reflection is a bit against the Golang's good practices since Golang aim explicit everything in the code right ?

Comment: @MEGADEVOPS Because a typical HTTP `POST` request takes the order of **hundred milliseconds** magnitude (including network delay), and the above `check()` function with reflection takes only half a **microsecond** to execute (called with a value of your `SignupModel` type). So with direct field comparison handling the POST request may be 200.0001 ms, and using this `check()` function it may be 200.0005 ms. You won't even notice the difference.